# Porque é que :first-child é uma pseudo classe?

Tags: css, pseudo-classes

Estou a dar uma formação em CSS, e mesmo depois de ler e ouvir sobre o tema ainda estou com algumas dificuldades em perceber porque :first-child é uma pseudo classe e não um pseudo elemento, como ::first-line, ::first-letter, etc.

Algum exemplo que me poderá esclarecer?

As pseudo classes que representam interações/estados percebem-se bem, esta é que me ficou atravessada tal como :nth-child() e semelhantes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É porque o `:first-child` não aponta a um elemento-filho do seu seletor, e sim que ***seu seletor é o primeiro filho de seu elemento-pai***. Por exemplo:

```
a:first-child{
    color: red;
}

<div>
   <a href="">Link 1</a>
   <a href="">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

O `a:first-child` indica que o primeiro `<a>` do elemento-pai `<div>` deve ter a cor vermelha.

```css
a:first-child{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="">Link 1</a>
   <a href="">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Já os *pseudo-elementos* apontam para elementos-filhos do seletor:

```
div::first-line{
    color: red;
}

<div>
   Foo
   <br />
   Foo2
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, a primeira linha da `div` deve ser vermelha.

```css
div::first-line{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Foo
   <br />
   Foo2
</div>
```

Comment: A  parte em negrito foi o que precisava para encaixar este assunto! Ty