# :first-child no .active do owl-carousel não funciona

Tags: javascript, css, css3, owl-carousel, pseudo-classes

Bom dia!

Estou usando o plugin owl-carousel que possui varios itens.
Preciso pegar o primeiro e o ultimo item da primeira pagina, mas nao estou conseguindo.

O carousel renderiza assim:

```
<div class="owl-stage">
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
   </div>
</div>
```

O itens da primeira pagina sao os que possuem a classe .active.
Tentei de algumas formas e nao funciona:

```
 .owl-stage .owl-item.active:first-child {
    border:red;
 }
 .owl-stage .active:first-child {
    border:red;
 }
.owl-item.active:first-child {
    border:red;
 }
```

Nao posso usar nth-child(n) pois a quantidade de itens varia muito. Entao preciso fazer de uma forma a pegar sempre o primeiro e o ultimo .active, independente de quantos itens tem.

obs.: desculpe a falta de acento, estou usando um vm e o teclado esta desconfigurado... :(

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar [Callbacks](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) para personalizar um evento.

Para não repetir linhas de código, criamos uma função:

```
function changeActive(e) {
    // Remove o seletor classe de todos item
    $('.owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('ativo');
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Adiciona o seletor classe nos item da pagina ativa
        $('.owl-stage .active:first').addClass('ativo');
        $('.owl-stage .active:last').addClass('ativo');
    },0);
}
```

Adicione na folha de estilo:

```
.ativo {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Crie a instancia do plugin

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
// Segundo a documentação, os eventos "initialize" e "initialized"
// devem ser anexados antes da inicialização do Carousel.
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', changeActive);
// Iniciamos o Carousel informando o callback
owl.owlCarousel({
    onChanged: changeActive,
    onTranslate: changeActive,
});
```

#### Exemplo

```js
function changeActive(e) {
  // Remove o seletor classe de todos item
  $('.owl-stage .owl-item').removeClass('ativo');
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Adiciona o seletor classe nos item da pagina ativa
    $('.owl-stage .active:first').addClass('ativo');
    $('.owl-stage .active:last').addClass('ativo');
  },0);
}
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', changeActive);
owl.owlCarousel({
  onChanged: changeActive,
  onTranslate: changeActive,
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ativo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

> **Obs.:** As vezes ao executar o código na primeira página buga, pois coloca o seletor por classe no primeiro e quarto item. Creio que seja um bug do próprio plugin.

#### Referência

- [Events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

Comment: Obrigada! Vou tentar!

Comment: Precisando é só comentar!

Answer (score 0):

## SEU CÓDIGO

Dentre suas regras CSS, essa é a única correta.

```
 .owl-stage .active:first-child {
    border:red;
 }`
```

## POSSÍVEL PROBLEMA

Se ela não tiver dado certo em seu projeto, talvez, você está referenciando o Owl na ordem errada. Veja como seria o certo:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Seu Título</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Como o exemplo acima mostra, os arquivos do carousel devem ser chamados antes de qualquer outra folha de estilo que você fez. Isso, por causa da cascata CSS.

## CONCLUSÃO

Utilize o seguinte código CSS:

```
.owl-stage .active:first-child {
        border:red;
}

.owl-stage .active:last-child {
        border:red;
}
```

E esse HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Seu Título</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

### Se o problema persistir

Use a keyword `!important`, assim:

```
.owl-stage .active:first-child {
        border:red !important;
}

.owl-stage .active:last-child {
        border:red !important;
}
```

Isso irá forçar o navegador utilizar essas propriedades.

## LINKS ÚTEIS

Aqui está alguns links para estudar sobre especificidade CSS:

- [Shay Howe](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/getting-to-know-css/#specificity);
- [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?biw=1366&bih=613&tbm=vid&ei=38eAWq-qE4P-wQT-1L_QBA&q=css%20especificidade&oq=css%20especificidade&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3131.5704.0.6088.15.14.0.0.0.0.241.1991.0j5j5.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.9.1771...0j0i8i30k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j0i19k1j0i8i13i30i19k1j0i8i30i19k1.0.Vr2n8PRqNcc).

Também tem links para estudar sobre seletores CSS:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp);
- [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Seletores%20css&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYnOyH-Z7ZAhVCIZAKHTW0Az4Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=662).

Agora, links a respeito do `!important`:

- [Zeno Rocha](https://zenorocha.com/css-important/).

Comment: A ordem dos css estao assim tambem...Nem pelo inspecionador de elementos funciona...

Answer (score 0):

O CSS não possui seletor para pegar elementos de forma dinâmica ou o *primeiro* ou *último* elemento baseado na **classe**.

A **[pseudo-classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249625/8063)** `:first-child` não pega o primeiro elemento que possui a classe, ela seleciona o primeiro *elemento-filho* do *elemento-pai* do seletor, (pareceu confuso? [Veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249625/8063)).

Já o jQuery e o JS puro conseguem selecionar esses elementos baseados na classe.

**Exemplo em jQuery:**

```js
var actives = $(".owl-stage .active"),
primeiro = $(actives).first(),
ultimo = $(actives).last();

primeiro.css("color","blue");
ultimo.css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-stage">
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
</div>
```

**Exemplo em JavaScript puro:**

```js
var actives = document.body.querySelectorAll(".owl-stage .active"),
primeiro = actives[0],
ultimo = actives[actives.length-1];

primeiro.style.color = "blue";
ultimo.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="owl-stage">
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item active"> (quero pegar esse)
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
   <div class="owl-item cloned">
      bla
   </div>
</div>
```